# opa gostaria de tira o subliando azul dos links

Tags: html, css, html5, estilo-de-codificação, style

.home ul {

```
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
background-color:#d3d3d2;
margin-top: -75px;

margin-left: 1400px;
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
font-family:Bahnschrift Condense;
padding: 12px;
text-align: center;
border: solid 2PX rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

}[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Basta adicionar o código abaixo:

```
.home ul, a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado me ajudou muito